# Apache + php 7 + FPM = sudden system breaks

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, fpm

I've an apache2 + php7 server running a simple wordpress blog.

The blog ran all the time with apache + mod_php + php7, but recently the during some access peak the system was crashing, getting to slow and even breaking.

So I googled how to optimize the configurations and many tutorials said mod_php is slow and I should replace it for php-fpm.

I did and after the change the site was noteciable faster, but now it randomly crashes and start presenting http 500 error...

There is no obvius reason for the new crashes, no users peak or any other situation I could notice.

the apache error log is plent of:

```
[fastcgi:error] [pid 37179] [client 162.158.167.177:26270] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi"
[fastcgi:error] [pid 37176] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 103.22.200.111:25406] FastCGI: comm with server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi" aborted: read failed, referer: http://www.fqn.com.br/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/jetpack.css
```

there are really thousands of errors like this, every two seconds one error and i dont understand.

**First why is apache asking a css to the fpm?**

**Second what "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi" is supposed to be? there is no file in this folder!! what is supposed to be there?**

The log of php-fpm is tottaly useless, I enabled the DEBUG level of loggind and what I get is just:

```
DEBUG: pid 1664, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 379: [pool www] currently 1 active children, 2 spare children, 3 running children. Spawning rate 2
```

every second one status message like this and at random intervals some:

```
WARNING: pid 1664, fpm_children_bury(), line 252: [pool www] child 38554 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 58.797353 seconds from start
```

but no stack trace or detailed error message to help me to understand. I really liked the performance of apache + fpm and didn't want to roll back to mod_php, but it's impossible to run the system for 12h without crashes in the current configuration.

the bellow link shows the php_info page of the server
https://jpst.it/11FIP

does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It is a programming fault.... somewhere in the php engine
and it seems to be invoked by a program setting it's input to non-blocking or stopping too soon after starting.

`(exec(), shell_exec(), proc_open() which fail)`...

It seems the PHP developers are not very eager, to put it mildly, to solve the issue. It has been known to exist for YEARS (2012 is the oldest ticket I have seen)

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73056